# $! echoing PID from parent script instead of last command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a service script that I'm more than likely using some non-conventional method to achieve what I want but nonetheless should work but isn't.

In the following commands I'm starting a process, saving the PID for that process to var `$PID`, and then writing the variable to a PID file. For some reason though when I'm saving the PID to `$PID`, the PID being written to the var is that of the parent script and not the last command ran.

How do I get the PID of the daemon command without doing some whacky `ps -ef | grep` stuff?

```
daemon --user $RHUSER "php -f $proc $ipaddr $port" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
PID=$!
[[ `ps h -p $PID` ]] && (success; echo $PID > /var/run/${proc%.*}.pid) || failure
echo
```

Comment: Are you sure that `daemon` command isn't a shell builtin or alias of some sort?

Comment: daemon is an OS function for Centos/RHEL that can be used by including ". /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions" at the top of your script.

Comment: If by "OS" you mean "bash", then it's pretty much expected that it doesn't have a distinct pid of its own.

Comment: yes, bash. I said OS because I've been told that /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions is something provided by the OS and can vary system to system.

Comment: What do you get from running this script: `echo "Parent = $$ (PID=$PID)";
sleep 5 &
PID=$!;
echo "Child = $PID"`?  For example, I got: `Parent = 6910 (PID=)
Child = 6911`.  Granted, `sleep` is not `daemon`, but I'm not clear whether that matters to you.  The other thing to be aware is that deamonizing programs typically fork and the ongoing child is isolated from the original shell — so the PID reported by `$!` may not be of much help anyway.

Comment: I get 2 different PIDs for the parent and child but the parent PID is dead and when I grep for the child it outputs the command I ran to launch the main service script, "/bin/bash /etc/init.d/myscript start".

Answer (score 0):

You could save the pid to a file with `-F` then read it from there:

```
daemon --user "$RHUSER" -F /tmp/pid.daemon "php -f $proc $ipaddr $port" >/dev/null 2>&1  ## Remove `&`
PID=$(</tmp/pid.daemon)
```

We remove `&` at the end of the command to make sure `daemon` writes the process ID of its child process before we read the PID file.

You can also use `--name` in combination with `-P`. Please see [manual](http://libslack.org/daemon/manpages/daemon.1.html).

Comment: We appear to be talking about 2 different daemon functions. This is from the shell script provided with Centos 6. http://pastebin.com/fQARW4JS

Comment: Does the function generate a pid file in `/var/run` somehow? Can you check if files are created there? I can't trace it in the code, but most parts of the script base on `$pid_file`. I wonder if you could use the `--pidfile` option.

Comment: By the way is not an option to use the binary `daemon` tool instead? And if you're in bash and that it's installed, you can call it with `command daemon args` even if the script is sourced to avoid the `daemon` function.

Comment: no, --pidfile doesn't create a pid file, it just checks it against a pid file if one is specified to check if there is an instance of the process already running. Also, I can't find anything in the yum repo called daemon so I don't know about that binary you're talking about.

Comment: It's seems like you could download the tool from here: http://libslack.org/daemon/. I hope there's a binary package that's compatible with your system. If not you could install it from source.